# VB6 Textbox values from unloaded form reappearing

Tags: vb6

I noticed that after my login form is unloaded, when the application is closed and another user reenters their information, the text boxes will automatically populate the form with the last user's data.

I am unloading the form with `Unload Me` then open a new form, but again, with a new login, the last user's login information is reappearing. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What is the data source of the login details? Do you have to refresh a database object or something like that?

Comment: If your application is closed, does it appear in task manager? Do you save/restore textbox values into/from some global variables or even outside the program?

Comment: Check out what's happening in Form_Initialize, Form_Load or Form_Activate.  There's probably logic for filling in the screen.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, no refresh at all. Basically they authenticate, if the record is found then `Unload Me` then open the new form.

Comment: @Arvo, I've never seen an instance lingering. Come to think of it though, I am not really closing the form. I have a `query_unload` routine that calls `Close`. Is this enough?

Comment: @BrianMStafford, I am setting some objects for Form2 (my second form that opens after a successful login). That is all I have in the Form_Initialize routine. I don't even have a `form_load` or `Form_Activate` routine.

Comment: Before unloading logon form just clear your text fields.